# athena - dynamically pivot rows to column

Tags: python, r, amazon-athena

I am trying to turn the values in a column into separate columns with the value coming from another column, similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48013254/how-to-pivot-rows-into-columns-in-aws-athena), except dynamically. In other words, I'm trying to turn a table form long to wide format, similar to the functionality of `spread` in `r` or `pivot` in `python`.

Is there a way to pivot a table in `athena` dynamically -- without having to hard code the columns to pull?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Athena (Presto) how to transpose map to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62717002/aws-athena-presto-how-to-transpose-map-to-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to write a query that results in different number of columns depending on the data. The columns must be known before query execution starts.