# AWS Athena create a binary matrix

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, binary, amazon-athena

Is it possible to create a binary matrix in AWS Athena from a table. For example we have the following table:

| name | product |
| --- | --- |
| John | Bike |
| John | Shirt |
| John | Ball |
| Blake | Shirt |
| Mike | Ball |
| Mike | Hat |

To be converted to the following:

| name | Bike | Shirt | Ball | Hat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Blake | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Mike | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: if thenumber of items is fixed, you can do pivot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48013254/how-to-pivot-rows-into-columns-in-aws-athena

Comment: No, the number of items is unknown

Comment: as you can read in the thread, building a dynamic sql approach will be time consuming, but you can try it

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Case expression:

```
select name, 
sum(case when product = 'bike' then 1 else 0 end) as "Bike",
sum(case when product = 'Shirt' then 1 else 0 end) as "Shirt",
sum(case when product = 'Ball' then 1 else 0 end) as "Ball",
sum(case when product = 'Hat' then 1 else 0 end) as "Hat"
from tableName
```